# How to convert cross sectional data to Transactional data in R

Tags: r

I have a cross sectional data like this:

```
**Type  Component_ID**
767 801307-00
767 468K29-2
777 263BA101-2
777 964-0453-011
320 6740B050000
320 305-439-401-0
320 1386M56P03
320 2131M81G02
320 2290B020000
319 1588M89G03
319 305-136-803-0
319 9238M66P08
767 801307-00
767 468K29-2
321 M20101-01
320 ACP2788AB04
```

I want to convert this to transactional data like this:

```
Type    Component_ID                
767 801307-00   468K29-2            
777 263BA101-2  964-0453-011            
320 6740B050000 305-439-401-0   1386M56P03  2131M81G02  2290B020000
319 1588M89G03  305-136-803-0   9238M66P08      
767 801307-00   468K29-2            
321 M20101-01               
320 ACP2788AB04
```

I tried dcast from reshape2 package

```
dcast(data1, Fleet_Type ~ Component_ID)
```

My results were like this:

```
  Fleet_Type 020-739-0 020-807-0 071-50001-8102 121664-10 121666-17 1386M56P03 1460M52P03 1498M96G01 1520M27P07
1        310         0         0              0         0         0          0          0          0          0
2        319         0         0              0         0         0          0          1          0          0
3        320         0         0              0         1         2          1          0          1          0
4        321         0         0              0         0         0          0          0          0          1
```

However i dont want count like this, rather i want the "wide" format.

I also tried reshape2

```
> reshape(data1, idvar = "Fleet_Type", timevar = "Component_ID", direction = "wide")
   Fleet_Type
1         767
3         777
5         320
10        319
15        321
50        330
63        310
Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for Component_ID=801307-00: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for Component_ID=468K29-2: first taken
3: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for Component_ID=9238M66P08: first taken
4: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
```

However I was just getting only the error messages.

Kindly help me on this

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is commonly called a long to wide transformation and there are many similar questions on here.

Comment: @Stedy - ok sir. I will try. Probably i didnt know the terminology. I will check for long to wide transformation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split `df1` data by `Type` and loop through it and collapse the values of `Component_ID`. Finally create a new data frame `df2` with the values from `a1`.

```
a1 <- lapply( with(df1, split(df1, Type)), function( x ) paste(x$Component_ID, collapse = ', ') )
df2 <- data.frame( Type = as.numeric(names(a1)), Component_ID = unlist(a1))
df2
#     Type                                                                 Component_ID
# 319  319                                        1588M89G03, 305-136-803-0, 9238M66P08
# 320  320 6740B050000, 305-439-401-0, 1386M56P03, 2131M81G02, 2290B020000, ACP2788AB04
# 321  321                                                                    M20101-01
# 767  767                                     801307-00, 468K29-2, 801307-00, 468K29-2
# 777  777                                                     263BA101-2, 964-0453-011
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Type = c(767L, 767L, 777L, 777L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 319L, 319L, 319L, 767L, 767L, 321L, 320L), 
                      Component_ID = c("801307-00", "468K29-2", "263BA101-2", "964-0453-011", "6740B050000", "305-439-401-0", 
                                       "1386M56P03", "2131M81G02", "2290B020000", "1588M89G03", "305-136-803-0", "9238M66P08",
                                       "801307-00", "468K29-2", "M20101-01", "ACP2788AB04")),
                 .Names = c("Type", "Component_ID"), row.names = c(NA, -16L),
                 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This has worked. Is it possible to print the component_ids in seperate columns instead of commas. I want to load this in Excel. Dont want commas. If you have any idea on this please help.

Comment: try `collapse = '  '` which will remove commas

Comment: The problem with having component ids in separate column is that component ids are of unequal length. You either store them as character vector or as a list. My answer is storing them as character vector.

Comment: Thank you this has worked. Sincere thanks for your help